# How to keep sshpass process in the background?

Tags: ssh, sshpass

`sshpass -p '1234567*' ssh -L 1080:192.168.0.1:2222 admin@gateway.com -p 4422 -f -C -N`

The above code works on macOS (creating a 1080 tunnel to 192.168.0.1:2222 via gateway.com:4422 with username admin and password 1234567*).\

It doesn't work on Linux - the process seems to run and terminate immediately.